# dynamically update php website

Tags: php, c++, sockets

Ok... I'm rather new to php (and I know this is probably a dumb question) but I am in the process of hooking up a C++ socket program to a php website.. Currently I can send strings to the website and all works well... Except... it only displays the stuff sent ONCE the php finishes executing...

Solutions I think will work:
 1. Make the page somehow run echo's whilest executing
 2. find a proper solution, i.e. setup a tcp connection and maintain throught the user sesion (how??) then execute a script which prints to the page apon receiving data

I've tried flush... didn't work

Actually, after thinking about it... Is there a solution where I can maintain a socket tcp connection even if the client changes page? That would be useful... Heres the source:

server(c++):
http://pastebin.com/QfaUrF92

client(php):
http://pastebin.com/hZXKsGN0

please note that I know how crap the code is.. It's just testing and fiddling to figure out what I can do and how I can do it

edit:

I'm trying to impliement my own Long Polling system through connecting a php session to a C++ server... I'de be willing to throw away sessions if it's gonna be dificult, but in the end I would love to be able to maintain a session so that I can fork a process to manage the client through out their browser changing pages

Comment: the question is, what do you want to do? it is not "a nice thing" to hook a c++ to a php website, rather update a datasource (database) with the info and fetch it from php. The dynamic change should be most likely done in javascript/ajax and not in php/c++

Comment: my issue is that I'm a C++ coder, not a php/www guy.. but unfortunatly I need it..

I'm implimenting a Long polling system if that helps.. I just want to create the system myself... I'm gonna assume that you can't maintain sockets in a browser session can you... 

Can I long poll with sockets? if not... How can I connect a C++ application to a php session so that I am able to manage the polling system

Comment: would one solution be SSE (server side events)

Then I could use thrift to send data recieved from client side events (i.e. form send) and C++ send data through thrift to be then used as a SSE... My only concern is scaleability.. small scale, yes this will work.. but large scale, will the php sse be too slow?

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic the sockets that I was using (due to my limited to knowledge of php) more than likely wouldn't be maintained in a session.. I am asking these questions as I have low knowledge of php and my main focus is the server side, php is just a necessary evil.

There is usually more than 1 solution to a problem.. So rather than make the wrong solution, I'm trying to ask those whom have experience and can suggest better routes

Comment: @MichaelCrook Browsers are not generally written in php, so I don't understand what you are getting at????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is executed server side, so once the page has been generated it's static. If you need the page content to constantly be updating, you can either use web sockets or ajax. Basically, AJAX will let your browser speak to your server using Javascript once the page has been rendered. Libraries like jQuery make it very simple.

From the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: That would be a tutorial on Websockets yes. That article is dated from 2010 and lots has changed. Websockets also aren't supported in some older browsers. If you need something that works in older browsers I would look at a combo of jQuery, ajax requests and long polling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NodeJS. It is server side JavaScript.

Using NodeJS you can build a socket connection between the browser page and your web server. Using this you can push data to the browser at the will of the server.

But it might take you some time to get started.

Recommended reading:

- [www.nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/)
- [www.nodebeginner.org](http://www.nodebeginner.org)
- [socket.io](http://socket.io)
- [hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html](http://hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html)